# Show that A is an open subset of M

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, proof-writing, circles

If $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $M=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $A \subseteq M$ is an open set of sequence where the number 1 appears at least $m$ times.

Show that $A$ is an open subset of $M$.

I wanted to show that if there exists a circle with center in $x$ that is $K(x,r) \subseteq A$ then $A$ will be an open subset. 
I'm not sure if that is the case though or how to show it.

EDIT: I know that

$$\mu (x,y) = \min\{n\in\mathbb{N} \ | \ x_n \not= y_n \}$$

and

$$d(x,y) = \frac{1}{\mu(x,y)}$$

and the metric space is given by $(M,d)$

Comment: What topology or metric are you using?

Answer (score 1):

First, let's get your terminology straight. You need to be more precise if you want to write proofs correctly. You're introducing the letters $x$, $r$ and $K$ without defining what they mean, and while you can usually infer some information from a name and context, it's better to be slightly more wordy. (Also, when asking questions like these: specify the topology! But you fixed that in the edit)

I'm assuming you want to use the criterion that a subset of a metric space $A \subseteq M$ is open if and only if **for each point** $x \in A$, we have that the open ball centred at $x$ with radius $\varepsilon$
$$ B(x, \varepsilon) = \{ y \in M : d(x, y) < \varepsilon \} $$
is fully contained in $A$.

So, first take any point $x$ in $M$. What does $B(x, \varepsilon)$ look like for different $\varepsilon$?

Once you've figured that out, take any point $x \in A$. Can you choose an $\varepsilon$ such that $B(x, \varepsilon)$ will be fully contained in $A$? Use the special property that you know about $A$.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. English isn't my first language so I don't know all the terms in English. 

As for the assignment, I'm not sure how to show that $d(x,y) < \epsilon$. If I had to choose an $\epsilon$ so $B(x,\epsilon)$ is fully contained in $A$, I'd say it would be something like $B(x, \{0,1\})$.

Comment: First try my first question. What does $B(x, \varepsilon)$ look like for different values of $\varepsilon$?

Comment: Or let's make it even more concrete. Say $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots)$, and $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{3}$. Can you describe $B(x, \varepsilon)$?

Comment: I have no idea to be honest.

Comment: Do you mean as for the radius and center?

Comment: I've given you the centre point $x$ and radius $\varepsilon$. What points lie in the open ball $B(x, \varepsilon)$? Obviously $x$ lies in there. What other points?

Comment: The radius, $\epsilon = \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Remember that a **point** is an element of your space $M$. The radius is a real number. To be fair, you're now asking questions at a way more elementary level than what your assignment is meant for. I think you need to take a few steps backwards and go over the material you're supposed to learn again. What's your background and in what context are you asking these questions?

Comment: This is just a thought. But do I need to show that $\exists \epsilon > 0: B(y,\epsilon) \subseteq B(x,\epsilon)$. So in $B(x,\epsilon)$ there is another point $y$ with radius $\epsilon$; $B(y,\epsilon)$?